# Heroku SSL with exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku, heroku-ssl

I am using [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-beta) and I need one of my Rails
controllers to **not** use SSL.

I tried a before_filter in my controller:

```
if request.ssl? && Rails.env.production?
  redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
end
```

Unfortunately, this ended in a `too many redirects` error. How can I create an exception for this controller? Thank you very much.

Comment: just curious, why would you not use ssl ?

Comment: That controller includes pages that have a websocket connection. [I am trying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133690/adding-wss-to-websocket-autobahn-wamp-twisted) to get that connection to work over WSS, but in the meanwhile I need the app to continue to work. (As it is, trying to load an SSL page with a WS connection causes browser errors.)

Comment: i think you should handle this in the web server end and not from the app. for ngnix check this out : https://github.com/nicokaiser/nginx-websocket-proxy

Comment: @Alfie Do you mean handle the website SSL over nginx or the websockets? I'm using Autobahn|JS for websockets.

Comment: Do the logs show any other filters doing redirects?

Comment: How do you redirect from http to https? Do you use the Rails force_ssl feature?